# Difference between repr() and !r

Tags: python, format

Following the [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#explicit-conversion-flag), I try to use as often as possible the format() method.
In the Explicit Conversion Flag chapter, it is possible to read:

> !r - convert the value to a string using
>   repr().

Indeed:

```
>>> "{0!r:10}".format('Hello')
"'Hello'   "
```

But:

```
>>> "{0.__repr__():10}".format('Hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__repr__()'
```

I don't understand why this exception is raised, because a string have always the **repr**() method !!??

```
>>> type('Hello')
<type 'str'>
>>> dir('Hello')
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

I think I miss something ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not saying there is no `__repr__` method; it's saying the value used for this placeholder has no attribute named `__repr__()`. The format string is not an arbitrary Python expression.

`"{0.foo}".format(x)` is roughly the same as `str(x.foo)`, not `str(x).foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully the error message. It says `__repr__()` was not found. Note the parenthesis in the attribute name. It is an invalid indentifier.

The reason is here:

```
"{0.__repr__():10}".format('Hello')
```

The expression inside curly brackets is a format string and it has its own [syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings). You can access items and attributes, but not call functions or build arbitrary expressions.